# Laravel LiveWire not showing simple global variable

Tags: ajax, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade, laravel-livewire

LiveWire no is displaying an Eloquent model; apparently, it only works when wrapping it in an array. However, I have always used it this way and have never had a problem.

This is my class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Revision;

use App\Models\Docs\ReqBusinessBasicInfo;
use Livewire\Component;

class BussinessBasicInfoComponent extends Component
{
    public $doc_schema;
    public $schema_container;

    public function mount(int $bussiness_id)
    {
        $this->doc_schema = ReqBusinessBasicInfo::find($bussiness_id);

        $this->schema_container = [
            $this->doc_schema
        ];
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.revision.bussiness-basic-infoo-component');
    }
}
```

And this is my blade:

```
<form>
    @csrf
    <x-text-input readonly disabled id="doc_schema.name" wire:model="doc_schema.name" />
    <x-text-input readonly disabled id="schema_container.0.name" wire:model="schema_container.0.name" />
</form>
```

The resul is this. One works the another not working.

[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8aRC.png)

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Livewire 3? Because then you need to explicitly enable legacy model binding, as explained [in the docs](https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/upgrading#eloquent-model-binding):

```php
'legacy_model_binding' => true,
```

If you're using Livewire 2, you **need** to define a `$rules` property with the keys you want to bind ([as explained in the docs](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/properties#binding-models)):

```php
public ReqBusinessBasicInfo $doc_schema;

protected $rules = [
    'doc_schema.name' => 'required|string',
];
```

Comment: I'm using laravel 9

Comment: I asked about Livewire, not Laravel. The Laravel version is not relevant in this case.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, and I realized that I don't have version 3. Instead, I have "livewire/livewire": "^2.12".